# RxJavaのメソッド compose の引数に、なぜラムダ式が渡せるのか

Tags: java, reactivex

例えば、Observableのメソッド　compose は以下の様に定義されています。
引数には ObservableTransformer　型の変数を渡すものと思いますが、これにラムダ式の関数を渡すことができるのは、なぜでしょうか。

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final <R> Observable<R> compose(ObservableTransformer<? super T, ? extends R> composer) {
    return wrap(((ObservableTransformer<T, R>) ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(composer, "composer is null")).apply(this));
}
```

Comment: ObservableTransformerの定義で @FunctionalInterface の様なものがあるのでしょうか。見る限りないのですが。

Answer (score 3):

ラムダを使えるためには メソッドが1つだけのinterface であればいいです。それだけが functional interface の要件です。

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method

---

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableTransformer.html

ObservableTransformer はそれを満たします。

---

@FunctionalInterface アノテーションはうっかり間違えて functional interface の条件を**満たさない**ように書いてしまった時に**警告する**ためのものです(@Override と同じように)。

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.9

Comment: そうだったんですね！！疑問が解けました。ありがとうございます！